# How to get the number of Results that returns through Find method in EMGU CV Pedestrian Detection C#

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I'm implementing a Pedestrian detection system using emgu cv library. The find method Returns number of results that detecting through the method.

```
public static Rectangle[] findPedestrian(Image<Bgr, Byte> image)
{
    Stopwatch stopwatch;
    Rectangle[] regions;
    if (CudaInvoke.HasCuda)
    {
        using (CudaHOG des = new CudaHOG(new Size(64, 128), new Size(16, 16), new Size(8, 8), new Size(8, 8)))
        {
            des.SetSVMDetector(des.GetDefaultPeopleDetector());
            stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            using (GpuMat cudaBgr = new GpuMat(image))
            using (GpuMat cudaBgra = new GpuMat())
            using (VectorOfRect vr = new VectorOfRect())
            {
                CudaInvoke.CvtColor(cudaBgr, cudaBgra, ColorConversion.Bgr2Bgra);
                des.DetectMultiScale(cudaBgra, vr);
                regions = vr.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        using (HOGDescriptor des = new HOGDescriptor())
        {
            des.SetSVMDetector(HOGDescriptor.GetDefaultPeopleDetector());
            stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            MCvObjectDetection[] results = des.DetectMultiScale(image);
            regions = new Rectangle[results.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < results.Length; i++)
                regions[i] = results[i].Rect;
            stopwatch.Stop();
        }
    }
    //processingTime = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    return regions;
}
```

And here it's generating the rectangles according to the results that sending through the process. What i want is to count the number of results that returning through the method. I thought to get it from the number of iterations of this foreach loop.

```
private Image<Bgr, Byte> imagingPedestrian(Image<Bgr, Byte> image)
{
    System.Drawing.Rectangle[] results = pedestrianDetection.findPedestrian(image);
    foreach (Rectangle rect in results)
    {
        CvInvoke.Rectangle(image, rect, new Bgr(Color.Red).MCvScalar);
    }
    return image;
}
```

Can i know a way to get that result. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If i understood correctly, results.count or results.length should work

Comment: I'm confused by the title and the question.  The title is about measuring how long something takes, but the question seems to be how many times a function is called.  Which is it?

Comment: The title doesn't matches the question.

Comment: @moorthidaniel, Thanks results.count worked for my problem.. Thanks a lot.. :)

Answer (score 0):

To count the time elapsed on each foreach iteration, you can use something like `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` class.

For example:

```
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
foreach(var myVar in myCollection)
{
   sw.Restart();

    /*
     * your iteration code...
     */

     sw.Stop();
     var timestampString = string.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}", sw.Elapsed.Hours.ToString("00"), sw.Elapsed.Minutes.ToString("00"), sw.Elapsed.Seconds.ToString("00"));
     Console.WriteLine("Elapsed time: {0}", timestampString);
}
```

Comment: it is not clear if he wants to count the results or measure the time

Comment: Agree... I took my chances :)

Comment: No, i want to get how many times the foreach loop iterated within the given case..

Comment: So did you check the code above to see if it gives you what you want ? At each iteration the `sw` instance will hold the elapsed time for the current one.

Comment: @Miu1994 this is not mentioned in your question. Please adjust your question and your title.

Comment: yea it getting number of results that passing through method and creating rectangles and displaying them correctly. I want to get the count of rectangles means the number of results that passing through the method.

Comment: @chris579 ok sure.

Comment: All right, so we have just made a big mess here :)  You just want the count of how many rectangles you just drawed ? Like everyone else say, you have that in `results.Count()`.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood the question you want to get the number of people detected...
if so you can get it by

```
results.Length
```